# Enabling BitLocker through Azure PowerShell failing on last step

Tags: azure, git-bash, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault, bitlocker

I actually did this once and it worked fine, but i had to create another VM and now it sems to be failing for some reason. So here are the steps that i followed in order to encrypt my C drive.

1.Created an AAD on my azure account along with a secret.
 2. Created a VM and downloaded all the necessary tools to encrypt
 3. Create a key vault for my VM and Ran the below script in azure powershell

```
$rgName = 'ResourceGroup';

$vmName = 'VM';

$aadClientID = 'ID';
$aadClientSecret = 'secret';

$KeyVaultName = 'BitBucketKey';
$KeyVault = Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName $KeyVaultName -ResourceGroupName $rgname;
$diskEncryptionKeyVaultUrl = $KeyVault.VaultUri;
$KeyVaultResourceId = $KeyVault.ResourceId;

Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $KeyVaultName -ServicePrincipalName 
$aadClientID -PermissionsToKeys all -PermissionsToSecrets all -ResourceGroupName $rgname;

Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $KeyVaultName -ResourceGroupName 
$rgname –EnabledForDiskEncryption

Set-AzureRmVMDiskEncryptionExtension -ResourceGroupName $rgname -VMName 
$vmName -AadClientID $aadClientID -AadClientSecret $aadClientSecret -DiskEncryptionKeyVaultUrl 
$diskEncryptionKeyVaultUrl -DiskEncryptionKeyVaultId $KeyVaultResourceId;
```

No matter what i try (hardcoding all variables), i still get the same error below

[image]

I know the key vault is enabled, but whats weird is the key vault and resource id i provide dont seem to match the error. Even when i hard code it. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently after you create a VM through azure(both RM and classic) and create a vault on that VM, it seems to permanently stick with it. I ended up creating a new VM from scratch and it worked. If anyone knows different please post here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, mine happened when I tried to run the command 3 times.  I ran it so many because in the VM it never showed as encrypted.

To fix, I ran the disable-azurermvmdiskencryption, I then went over to the keyvault and deleted the secrets for this vm (you can tell its the right secret by looking at the tags).  I then deallocated and reallocated the vm.  I then ran the enable command again, and everything worked.